# How to multiply values which returns web services and see in listView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

Here is my code!  I want to multiply user cost with 12. and I want to add this count(cost*12) to list view.But I add only String columns to list view because of list adapter.How can also add integer value by multplying ?

```
static final String KEY_ITEM= "USER_ID";   
static final String KEY_NAME = "USER_NAME";
static final String KEY_SURNAME = "USER_SURNAME";
static final String KEY_DATE = "USER_DATE";
static final String KEY_COST="USER_COST";


HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
map.put(KEY_ITEM, conParser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM));
map.put(KEY_NAME, conParser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
map.put(KEY_SURNAME, conParser.getValue(e, KEY_SURNAME));
map.put(KEY_DATE, conParser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
map.put(KEY_COST, conParser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));

items.add(map); 

final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] {KEY_ITEM,KEY_NAME,KEY_SURNAME,temp,KEY_DATE,KEY_COST}, new int[] {
                    R.id.kod, R.id.isim,R.id.kisi_sayisi,R.id.adisyon_sayisi,R.id.toplam_satis});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I want to say that this cost values returned from a web service.

Comment: Before add it to the map get the String and manipulate the data. Integer cost=Ingeter.valueOf(String)*12;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before add it to the map get the String and manipulate the data.

> Integer cost=Ingeter.valueOf(String)*12; 
>   cost.toString();

Comment: When I did like this, it didn't work! For example, I want to multiply KEY_DATE and KEY_COST.As a result, I want to add list item,too.It is absurd, I know but I give this as a sample.Please help me..